# why my onCreateViewHolder is calling all the items at a time?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to display thousand list items on a screen so I Created an adapter in that, `onCreateViewHolder` is calling all the items at a time.As it should call only some items at a time in `recycled view`.How to know where is the error?

Comment: try adding your code here, have a look here before posting questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you elaborate by `is calling all the items at a time`?

Comment: Please post some code so we can know what's going on there